# Удаление кеша в браузере у пользователей

Tags: php, кэширование, браузер

Всем привет. Заметил такую штукенцию, что при обновление сайта изменения не отображаются или отображаются не корректно. Прочитал, что после стилей в можно сделать GET запрос. Например:

```
/css/style.css?1
```

- 1 тем самым должна заставить обновить стили о пользователя, но этот метод на практике оказался бесполезным. Подскажите, какие есть альтернативные способы очистки кеша? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передавать заголовки:

```
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Но сам не пользуюсь подобными вещами, т.к. проблем никогда не возникало.

Для скриптов использовал параметры типа `/style.css?<?= intval(microtime(1)) ?>`

Comment: Кеш нужно удалить один раз после обновления сайта. Но самое странное, что не работает GET после стилей. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

/css/style.css?1 если так то оно эквивалентно /css/style.css и закэшируется
если /style.css?`<?= intval(microtime(1)) ?>` то урл будет новый и будет воспринят браузером как новый файл и обновится но лучше в качестве GET переменной использовать время последней модификации файла.